# AvalonDock (2.0) + MVVM + VSPackage = document selection trouble?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, vs-extensibility, avalondock

I have a control that utilizes an AvalonDock (2.0) `DockingManager` control for displaying a set of documents managed by an underlying view model:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DocumentItem}"/>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    <avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDockLayout:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <avalonDockLayout:LayoutDocumentPane/>
        </avalonDockLayout:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

The document view model has an `IsSelected` property, and when the view model is selected, I want to select and show the document in the `DockingManager`.  To do this, I updated the `Style` for `LayoutItem` as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="DocumentItem" TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutItem}">
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.TabTitle}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

This approach works fine when the control is hosted within a WPF application, but when the control is hosted within a VSPackage, selecting the document in the view model more often than not does not bring the selected document into view.  In the image below, the user clicked on the Customer node to edit, but the customer document did not come into view.

[image: AvalonDock issue]

The view model layer is setting `IsSelected` as expected, and when the control utilized a `TabControl`, the selected document always showed on top.

It appears to be an issue within AvalonDock.  What I am finding is when a `LayoutItem` is selected via the view model, the first document in the list is being reselected to true at the `LayoutDocument/LayoutContent/LayoutElement` layer, which trickles back up and resets `IsSelected` to true at the `LayoutItem` layer.  I would love to bind `IsSelected` to my view model at the `LayoutDocument/LayoutContent/LayoutElement` layer, but there is no `DependencyProperty` at that layer.

I've tried alternate ways of binding `IsSelected` to my view model, but so far without success.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  Know of any workarounds or other approaches?  I'd hate to resort to having to using a non MVVM approach, just to do document selection.

**Edit:** It seems like this issue may by obscure, as I'm having difficulty creating a reproducing test case, even with a VSPackage.  In the following test case that simulates the actual controls with dual `ToolWindow`s and Mediator messages, the document selection works fine.

[image: Tool Windows]

This test case (with a WPF app and a VSPackage) is available [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=0E945D83357E9465&id=E945D83357E9465!108&sc=documents#cid=0E945D83357E9465&id=E945D83357E9465!299&sc=documents) (click on `Tools=>My command name` to launch tool windows, and enter a document title in one window to choose or create and select a document in the window with the `DockingManager`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm putting a bounty on this one, as I'm sure others will run into this issue one way or another, and there should be a better solution.

At the moment, I have a horrible hack to get document selection to work:

1. I maintained the same `IsSelected` binding to my document view model in the `LayoutItem` style.
2. In my main view model, I added a `SelectedItem` property to track which document is selected programatically (by an edit event, etc.).
3. I added an event handler for `ActiveContentChanged` on the `DocumentManager` control, and in this method I reselect the `SelectedItem` in my view model if it is not selected.  AvalonDock tries up to a half dozen times to reselect the first document in the list before giving up!
4. I added an event handler for `PreviewMouseDown` on the `DocumentManager` control, and in this method I null the view model `SelectedItem` so that user initiated selection continues to work.

Again, looking for a better answer to this!

Comment: I haven't worked with Avalon inside VS (is it 2010/12?) - but I've seen many similar problems (w/ different Avalon components). One question, just 'humor me' :) - does the 'document selection' that triggers the whole issue - come from mouse or keyboard? (i.e. the underlying 'source' of the event). And btw. do you have any simple repro project - I could take a look - but I have little time to set it all up.

Comment: I'm running into the issue in VS2010, haven't tried it in 2012 yet.  The document selection that triggers the issue arises when the user chooses to edit a document.  A message (using the Mediator design pattern) is sent from the tree view control/window to the "designer" control/window that has the DockingManager.  If the designer view model does not have the document, it is added, and in all cases the associated document view model has IsSelected set to true.  From the DockingManager standpoint, it should just be seeing an updated list of documents and/or a change in a document IsSelected.

Comment: No time today, but I'll look at creating a sample project tomorrow.  I'll try to induce the error outside of a VSPackage.  In order to run DockingManager within a VSPackage, AvalonDock will need to be installed in the GAC or some other known place.